# Inotifywait exclude all except specific files

Tags: bash, shell, sh, inotifywait

So I know you can exclude files from being watched but what about the other way ? What if I only want to watch *.txt only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the names you want to watch as arguments:

```
intotifywait ... *.txt
```

If you are concerned the pattern will match too many files to fit on the command line, you can use the `--fromfile` arguments to read the list of files to monitor from a file. The file needs to contain the actual file names, not a pattern, so you might need to create the file with something like

```
for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' "$f"; done > files.txt
inotifywait --fromfile files.txt ...
```

Comment: the command seems to work only if a txt file exists but the directory might be empty in my case and I want it to keep runnin in a while loop

Comment: In that case, you aren't really watching the files, but rather the directory itself.